# Arabic language in JForum

Tags: java, tomcat8, glassfish-4

Hi i'm trying to convert the [Jforum](http://jforum.net/) GUI to be in Arabic language and created Arabic file in `config --> languages` and choose this file in the Jforum `Default board Language` in `configurations`
but i get the Arabic characters as shown [image]
 so i set the `Character Encoding` in the forum configuration to `UTF-8` but still getting the same results , also tried to add to the JVM `-Dfile.encoding=UTF8` but still getting the same , i deployed it on `Glassfish` and `Tomcat` and both have the same error.

Any recommendations to fix this issue.

Comment: any help or advice ?